# How to customize default sizes new created objects

Tags: modeling, objects, units

I work with metric system and units in millimeters. But all new geometry from Shift+A is 200mm. How can I change it?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the "Add Plane" window to change value from 200mm to 150mm al subsequent planes added to this file will start with 150mm. You can then File->Defaults->SetStartupFile" to use this file as your default file.